# My variables updated in a function don't work outside the function

Tags: python, function, variables

```
hi = 1
result = 0
def hello(x):
    x = x + 10
    result = x
helli(hi)
print(result)
```

Why does my code Output "0" and not 11?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have a typo in `helli`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the keyword global for that. Then edited values inside the function actually impact the variable from outside the function. **This is not the recommended approach.**

```
hi = 1
result = 0

def hello(x):
    global result
    x = x + 10
    result = x

hello(hi)
print(result)
```

The recommended approach is, however, to return such value:

```
def hello(x):
    return x + 10

hi = 1
result = 0
result = hello(hi)
print(result)
```

Comment: Relevant: [Global variables are _evil_!](//stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/843953)